# Swift: calling function from another viewcontroller makes objects nil

Tags: ios, swift

I have two simple ViewController: the first one has a IBOutlet linked to a UIImageView and a function that sets the image alpha channel. The second controller has a button that, when it's trigged, should call the function to set the alpha channel.

Here my code:

```
class FirstViewController: UIViewController {

     @IBOutlet imageView: UIImageView! 

     func changeAlphaChannel() {
         imageView.alpha = 0.5
     }
}

class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

     let firstController = FirstViewController()

     @IBAction func buttonPressed(sender: UIButton) {
         firstController.changeAlphaChannel()
     }
}
```

Calling `changeAlphaChannel()` inside FirstViewController works as aspected, but if I call it pressing the button, `imageView` becomes nil and the app crashes.
How can I fix this? 
Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Its crashing because your imageView is nil. Just initialising `firstController` with `FirstViewController()` will not do. You'll have to load that view controller from storyboard. You can do it this way

```
let storyboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard.init(name: "StoryboardName", bundle: nil)
let firstViewController: FirstViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("StoryboardIdentifier") as! FirstViewController
```

**UPDATE**

Now IBOutlets of firstViewController will be set only when firstViewController's view is instantiated, which in your case is not happening. What you have to do is first display view of firstViewController and then call your function.

Comment: Thanks for the reply,
I tried your solutions but calling `firstViewController.changeAlphaChannel()` returns the same error:
**fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value**
and imageView is still nil

Answer (score 1):

You're not calling the function on the first controller - you're creating a new instance of the first controller, which doesn't have anything set in the image.

You need to pass a reference to the first controller through to the second.

Answer (score -1):

In swift we need to check operators are nil or not, try this

imageView?.alpha = 0.5

instead of

imageView.alpha = 0.5